# Client Secret In Chrome Web Store API

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, chrome-web-store

I am trying to use Chrome Web Store API and I have followed this link https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api

But after creating application on developers console I am not getting client secret which is used to get the access token.

Please help me in finding the SECRET TOKEN.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you exhaustively searched in your developer's console?

Comment: Yes, I did. I also tried downloading the secret json file.

Comment: Visit [here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials).  Click an API project and you should the app key and secret displayed to you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: it is written on documents " a JavaScript application does not require a secret, but a web server application does.". And I have a chrome extension. Do I still require secret token if no then how would I get the access token? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Review some documentation on using OAuth 2.0 from JavaScript.  This should clear up any confusion you might have about the workflow.

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution by simply passing the client secret blank in the request.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this...saying "check the documentation" is a frustratingly stupid response from more experienced hands who don't remember that one literal syntactical difference can screw up a newbie...